# AVCaptureVideoDataOutput wrong orientation using the front camera in RosyWriter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, avcapturesession

I download the IOS samplecode [RosyWriter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011110) and modify it using the **front camera** instead.
The problem is that the video is a mirror.That is to say,when my head turn right
, in the video,it turns left.However,the head up and down is right.
What seems the problem,can anyone give me a hand,sorry for my poor english.
here is part of my code,i set the orientation like this

```
videoConnection = [videoOut connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
self.videoOrientation = [videoConnection videoOrientation];
[videoOut release];
```

however someone say that ***AVCaptureVideoDataOutput*** can not handle the orientation,
what can i do?

here is some related question i found
[1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640746/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-deal-with-avcapturevideodataoutput-image-data-reg) [2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823461/how-to-change-video-orientation-for-avcapturevideodataoutput) [3.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823461/how-to-change-video-orientation-for-avcapturevideodataoutput) [4.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640746/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-deal-with-avcapturevideodataoutput-image-data-reg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hardware-level thing that Apple's done since the very first desktop iSights. The idea is that front-facing cameras are generally used for videoconference, "FaceTime" they call it these days, right? Well, think about if the person was facing you in person. They'd see the "mirrored" image of you, right? So the preview shows you as you look from the person you're talking with. If it shot you un-mirrored, then the other person would see you reversed.

So this is not an "orientation" issue. Orientation is just the rotation angle. This is "mirroring" or "flipping". You'll need to reverse that by applying this transform to the raw frames,

mirror_transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0);

or the equivalent in whatever image space it suits you to work in; and then output those mirrored frames to preview/movie/photo/whatever.

Comment: i came up with one thing,the data from camera is rendered to opengl es as texture,i just flip the texture,the problem is solved.