# AVFoundation - how to mirror video from webcam - Mac OS X

Tags: macos, avfoundation, webcam-capture

I am trying to mirror video received from webcam on mac os x. I would like to *avoid doing a manual flip/tranform* after receiving the video buffer . So, I want to setup `AVCaptureSession` such that video buffer received in `captureOutput` method of `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` is mirrored by AVFoundation itself. I don't want to use the preview layer.

On an iMac(10.8.5), to mirror video, `AVCaptureConnection isVideoMirroringSupported` is successfully tested before setting the `videoMirrored` property. But video buffer received in `captureOutput` delegate isn't mirrored.

Note: Video mirroring on iOS was successful, when I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4979450/1180117) SO answer. But it isn't helping on mac os x.

Code used is below. Error checking is left out for this post.

```
    //create session
    _session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    //get capture device
    _device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    //create sesion input
    NSError * error;
    _sessionInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:_device error:&error];

    //create session output
    _sessionOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [_sessionOutput setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES];
    [[_sessionOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] setEnabled:YES];
    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
    [_sessionOutput setVideoSettings:videoSettings];

    //serial queue to process video frames
    dispatch_queue_t videoOutputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("deviceeraQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    [_sessionOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:videoOutputQueue];

    //begin session configuration
    [_session beginConfiguration ];

    //input and output for session
    if( [_session canAddInput:_sessionInput]) {
        [_session addInput:_sessionInput];
    }
    if( [_session canAddOutput:_sessionOutput]) {
        [_session addOutput:_sessionOutput];

    }

    //set video mirroring
    AVCaptureConnection* avConnection = [_sessionOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if( [avConnection isVideoMirroringSupported]) {
        avConnection.videoMirrored = YES;
        NSLog(@"Video mirroring Support: YES"); // this line is printed
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Video mirroring Support: NO");
    }

    //set session preset    
    [_session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];
    [ _session commitConfiguration ];

    ...........
    ...........

    - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
    {
    .........
    //sampleBuffer is not mirrored video
    ........
```

Of lesser importance 1 -  though C++, I also tried looking into OpenCV's VideoCapture implementation for way to mirror video. But, OpenCV don't mirror video from Mac(uses flip). Left is libVlc/V4L.

Of lesser importance 2 - In slide 73 of [this](http://docs.huihoo.com/apple/wwdc/2010/session_409__using_the_camera_with_av_foundation.pdf)  2010 wwdc apple presentation (3Mb pdf), there is a mention that `setVideoOrientation` is not supported on 'AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` connection. But in 2013, apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1744/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011134) are updated and  supports this method.

Comment: Found the same behavior on the `isVideoMirrored` API,  I uses a preview layer, the preview layer can be set mirrored correctly but I used an `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` to actually record the video, in the output delegate: `captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)` the sample buffer is not mirrored.

Answer (score 6):

You can add a transform on the preview layer to flip x value of the frames before they get to the preview window.

```
[[self previewLayer] setTransform:CATransform3DMakeScale(-1, 1, 1)];
```

Then you can run the recorded video through export session and do the same transformation.  That way the video preview will match the final recorded video.  Bit of a hack, but it gets the same results.

Comment: Thanks. But in question, I had mentioned about reluctance to use preview layer ( in paragraph 1 )

Comment: OSX does not respect the videoMirrored property, probably a bug.  Using a preview layer is the only way I've found to achieve the effect.

Answer (score 5):

Why hack it when it's very easy. Just set automaticallyAdjustVideoMirroring of your AVCaptureConnection then set it manually.

```
    aPreviewLayer.connection.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring = NO;
    aPreviewLayer.connection.videoMirrored = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks. But kindly see my mention about reluctance to you preview layer ( in paragraph 1 of question). The same is again mentioned in my comment to the earlier answer.

Comment: I don't think you can without using the preview layer. But you can certainly achieve the same effect by for example scaling. Scaling buffer by (x,y,z) = (-1,1,1) would achieve the mirroring affect :)

Comment: `I don't think you can without using the preview layer.` - Then to close the question, to support that, we will need a valid source document or an accepted bug report by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5 version of "Þorvaldur Rúnarsson" answer:**

```
previewLayer.connection?.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring = false
previewLayer.connection?.isVideoMirrored = true
```